# Azure.cosmos Feediterator skipping entries allocates lots of memory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am querying a table in cosmos with 350k entries.
The query itself gets all entries after a timestamp and skips 399k entries so the output should be empty.

The timestamp is the start of the universe, so in effect it is all entries in the table.
This query takes around 16 seconds which is understandable, but while the query runs, it allocates 1 GB of memory.

I'm really pushing cosmos and I know that this is perhaps not the way it was meant to be used, but is the large allocation of memory expected behavior or a bug?

Here is the sql query generated:

```sql
SELECT VALUE root
FROM root
WHERE (((root["ObjectType"] = "dummytype") 
AND (root["Context"] = null))
AND (root["timestamp"] > -62135596800)) 
ORDER BY root["timestamp"] ASC
OFFSET 399000 LIMIT 1000
```

Below is a graph of memory usage during this query.
[image: Memory graph for 399000 offset query]

I am running with the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos (3.31.2).

Since the query should simply skip all entries and return an empty result, i would expect the memory to be much much lower.

It seems that memory usage scales with the offset of the query as shown in this table:

| Offset | Memory |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25MB |
| 99000 | 390MB |
| 199000 | 618MB |
| 299000 | 859MB |
| 399000 | 1005MB |

Is it expected that the memory usage scales with how long the iterator has to traverse? I would expect it to only load some of the table at a time and then leave previous segments to be garbage collected, but as can be seen in the memory graph the memory footprint rises steadily despite multiple GC's

Comment: it's not really clear what your issue is, especially around your "issue vs bug" comment. Please edit to be specific. Include any relevant detail as well.

Comment: I would expect the database to process the rows which are to be skipped due to the OFFSET part of the query in the database, not sending them to the client at all. Thus I would expect your query to be slow and potentially very expensive for the database, but not expensive in terms of client memory.